# Connection string to SQL Express

Tags: sql, database, string, express, connection

I am thinking how to connect to database located on the server accessible through port
(random numbers)
i.e. 34.12.122.212:6669  - access to the phisical server via firewall

```
string ConnectionString = "server=34.12.122.212\\SQLEXPRESS,6669; User Id=xxx;Password=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=true; Database=xxxxx; Integrated Security=false";
```

I know this will not work as sql server TCP/IP Port will be 1433.
Is there any way to connect to this sql server?